# overloading the "dot" operator in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, operator-overloading

I have written a simple class in MATLAB to manage a set of key-value pairs. I would like to be able to access the keys using a dot after the object name like:

```
params.maxIterations
```

instead of:

```
params.get('maxIterations')
```

Is it possible to override the dot operator so that it calls my get() method?

I have tried to override the subsasgn() method as suggested [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/29018-is-it-possible-to-overload-dot-notation-operator) but I couldn't figure out how I should write it.

Comment: Typical convention to access a value from a key-value pair container is to overload `operator[]` so you can use `params[Key]`. Even if what you're asking for is possible, it doesn't make much sense semantically because that syntax makes it look like the keys are *part of* the container instead of objects *stored within* the container. Also, what if your keys are integers instead of strings, do you expect `params.42` to work?

Comment: Thanks for the point. I guess I should override () in MATLAB then?

Comment: That's what the builtin [`containers.Map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map-class.html) class does too.

Comment: Thank you. You might copy your comment as a post so I can accept as answer.

Comment: That's alright, it's too short to be worthy of an answer. I think it'd be better if you posted the operator() you implement as the answer, might help someone else who's looking to do the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [dynamic properties](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_oop/dynamic-properties--adding-properties-to-an-instance.html). Then instead of adding a list of strings, you add a new property for each 'key'. Get all keys with `properties(MyClass)` (of just `fieldnames(MyClass)`

However, I think it's indeed best to overload `subsref`, but note that doing that *properly*  can eat away the majority of a work week if you do it for the first time...It's not that it's really difficult, it's just that the `()` operator *does* so much :)

Luckily, you don't have to. Here's how:

```
classdef MyClass < handle

    methods

        function result = subsref(obj, S)

            %// Properly overloading the () operator is *DIFFICULT*!!
            %// Therefore, delegate everything to the built-in function, 
            %// except for 1 isolated case:

            try
                if ~strcmp(S.type, '()') || ...
                   ~all(cellfun('isclass', S.subs, 'char'))

                    result = builtin('subsref', obj, S);

                else                    
                    keys = S.subs %// Note: cellstring; 
                                  %// could contain multiple keys

                    %// ...and do whatever you want with it

                end

            catch ME
                %// (this construction makes it less apparent that the
                %// operator was overloaded)
                throwAsCaller(ME);   

            end

        end % subsref method

    end % methods

end % class
```